# change css attributes after slider class changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I am using codetabs.js for my project and now I have a problem: I have a tab box with 4 tabs and want to organize those to side by side layout , I mean content of next tab shows at side of active tab . I use this jquery code :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".ct-ready.ct-cur").next().css({"visibility": "visible", "margin-left": "45%"});
 }); 
</script>
```

and it works but just for first tab and when active tab changed attributes which I added doesn't remove and next tab (number 3 tab) hasn't any attributes .

how can I solve this problem to Dynamically change of attributes after class change ? or how to use another way to side by side tabs ?

thanks for your answers.

I should also mention that the callback event of tab change is :

```
code.ev.on('selectID', function() {
```

and id used it too , this one problem is just the attributes doesn't remove after class change I think solve this on is easier

Comment: possible for you to put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: I do not think, Because it is a full page project but I will try

Comment: I see. Is the project live, possible to share a URL?

Comment: it is not live , and biger problem is the codetabs script ; it is premiom an maybe made so,e problems , I do not know the rules